# Getting error setting a property on the result object in ibatis

Tags: ibatis

I am unable to identify the solution for below error

```
[sm.vo.BankVO@2329219a].  Cause: com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:   
--- The error occurred in sm/sql/sm.xml.  
--- The error occurred while applying a result map.  
--- Check the getbanktMap.  
--- The error happened while setting a property on the result object.  
--- Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number


public class BankVO implements Serializable{


    private String rol1,rol2,rol3,rol4,rol5,rol6,rol7,rol8,rol9,rol10;
//setters and getters

}
```

Please help on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe that the problem is in the mapper.
The Oracle error code ORA-01722 means "invalid number", please check your mapper as written in the log:

--- Check the getbanktMap.